# KL divergence for Generalized Extreme Value distribution

Tags: kullback-leibler, weibull-distribution, extreme-value, gumbel-distribution

I have found a derivation for the Kullback–Leibler divergence between 2 Gumbel distributions here:
http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~communications/Papers/gil-msc11.pdf on page 64

That document also has a derivation for the KL divergence between 2 univariate Weibull distributions on page 67.

Is there a derivation, or solved formula, for the KL divergence between 2 univariate [Generalized Extreme Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution) distributions?  Or, are there a set of KL formulas for all of the combinations that make up the GEV (e.g. Gumbel-Gumbel, Gumbel-Frechet, Gumbel-Weibull, Frechet-Gumbel, Frechet-Frechet, Frechet-Weibull, Weibull-Gumbel, Weibull-Frechet, Weibull-Weibull)?

If there's one unifying formula, what is it and where can I find a reference for it.  If there are several, what are they and where are they referenced?

Comment: If you're looking for a general formula for the KL divergence $D_{KL}(F_1,F_2)$ between two extreme value distributions, you should first notice that whenever you select two distributions  $F_1$ and $F_2$ whose parameters provide them with supports such that the density of $F_1$ is positive over a region where the density of $F_2$ "is null", then $D_{K,L}(F_1,F_2)=\infty$. This will be the case for most of the combinations you may come up with.

Comment: Thus, I think, you should rather concentrate on a specific distribution class (Gumberl, Weibull or Fréchet)  and parametrize it in such a way that the support is fixed.